# Magento 2 : How to get all the attributes of a product added to the cart?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I am developing an extension for Magento 2 and would like to get all the properties/attributes of the products in the cart. The code needs to be generic so that it can adapt to any kind of product.

For example, if a T shirt is added, I need to get color & size and if a Ring is added, I need to get MetalType, Purity and similar attributes. I am able to get all possible options, but not the attributes of the selected product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve this using the following lines:

```
$options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
        $itemProps = array();
        if(array_key_exists('attributes_info', $options)) {
                $attributes = $options['attributes_info'];
                 foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
                        $itemProps[$attribute['label']] =  $attribute['value'];
         }
        }
```